# Let $G_1=G/Z(G)$ for a group $G$. Let $G_{i}$ be the group $G_{i-1}/Z(G_{i-1})$. If $G_{k}/Z(G_{k})$ is abelian, is $G$ nilpotent?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $Z(G)$ be its center.  Now let $G_{1}$ be the group $G/Z(G)$ and $Z(G_{1})$ be its center. Inductively let $G_{i}$ be the group $G_{i-1}/Z(G_{i-1})$.

If for some $k$ we have that $G_{k}/Z(G_{k})$ is abelian can we deduce that the original group is nilpotent?

I think that there is a connection with the upper central series of a group defined by the normal subgroups

$$Z_{i}(G)=\{g\in G : [g,h] \in Z_{i-1}(G) \hspace{1mm} \forall h \in G\}$$

but I'm not sure I fully understand it.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: @Shaun you should propose a title if you are going to make that request.

Comment: Not necessarily, @PrinceM.

Comment: It's not exactly a request either, @PrinceM.

Comment: "Please do ______ " is not a request? @Shaun

Comment: In this case, it is not, @PrinceM. It is advice.

Comment: @Shaun So what is wrong with me, in turn, giving you advice?

Comment: Nothing, @PrinceM. What is your problem with well-established, sensible etiquette in this case? What kind of a title do you think "nilpotent groups" is?

Comment: Grow up, @PrinceM.

Comment: @Shaun Is that a request or advice?

Comment: It looks to me as though the series that you have defined is exactly the upper central series! In fact it arguably the "standard" definition of the upper central series.

Comment: The title of this post is not brilliant,  but I have seen far worse, like "An interesting problem in group theory".

Comment: @Shaun I understand that the title is a little abstract but I couldn't think of a better one since I ask a a question about the definition of a nilpotent group and if the described situation is a consequence of the definition. Although I agree I should be more specific in the title I don't think the rest of the conversation is helpful for this post.

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you explain this in a little more detail? How are the groups $G_{i}/Z(G_{i})$ the groups $Z_{i}(G)$?

Comment: The group $G_i/Z(G_i)$ is isomorphic to the group $G/Z_i(G)$. You define $G_1$ to be $G/Z(G)$, which is exactly $G/Z_1(G)$. You define $G_2$ to be $G_1/Z(G_1)$, that is, to be $G/Z_1(G)$, modulo its center. But $Z_2(G)$ is precisely the group such that $Z_2(G)/Z_1(G) = Z(G/Z_1(G))$; so $G_1/Z(G_1) = (G/Z_1(G))/Z(G/Z_1(G)) = (G/Z(G))/(Z_2(G)/Z(G)) \cong G/Z_2(G)$. Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just defining the quotients of $G$ by its upper central series, but with different notation.

Recall that the upper central series is defined recursively by letting $Z_0(G)=\{e\}$, $Z_1(G)=Z(G)$, and $Z_{i+1}(G)$ to be the subgroup of $G$ such that $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G) = Z(G/Z_i(G))$.

I claim that your definition of $G_i$ just gives $G_i\cong G/Z_i(G)$.

Indeed: you define $G_1=G/Z(G) = G/Z_1(G)$, so this holds.

Assume that $G_i\cong G/Z_i(G)$. You then define $G_{i+1}$ to be the group $G_i/Z(G_i)$. Now, $Z_{i+1}(G)$ is precisely the subgroup of $G$ such that $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G) = Z(G/Z_i(G))$. Therefore, $Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)$ is precisely the group which corresponds to $Z(G_i)$ under the isomorphism $G/Z_i(G)\cong G_i$. Thus,
$$G_{i+1} = \frac{G_i}{Z(G_i)} \cong \frac{G/Z_i(G)}{Z_{i+1}(G)/Z_i(G)} \cong \frac{G}{Z_{i+1}(G)}.$$
This establishes the claim.

So your question amounts to: if $G/Z_i(G)$ is abelian for some $i$, does it follow that $G$ is nilpotent? Answer: that's one of the standard definitions of "nilpotent group".